# Prisma, after prisma db push I always have to turn off IDE

Tags: prisma

Prisma, after npx prisma db push I always have to turn off IDE and turn on IDE

Otherwise, autoComplete suggestionComplete does not appear and redline appears in the node js code section.

I use GoLand

there is no workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try the GO Client with VS Code and check if you get the same error.

On a side note: Prisma Client GO is not officially maintained anymore, here's the GitHub Issue which describes this in detail: [#707](https://github.com/prisma/prisma-client-go/issues/707)

Comment: I like GoLand and I use Node js not Go lang here.. I think there is no way.. okay it is not that critical issue it`s fine